# how to get value from combobox bind From List<>

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `combobox` that is bind with List<> type data . When i select something in `combobox` and try to find the `SelectedItem` from the `combobox` i found nothing . How can i get this 
i am attaching my code picture you can understand. [image]

Here i want to get the `SelectedItem` `FiscalYearName` that the user select from the `combobox`

Comment: What is the type of the items inside the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var item =  fiscalYearComboBox.SelectedItem as FiscalYear
 if(item!=null)
   _fPeriod.FiscalYear = item.FiscalYearName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to cast the `ComboBox` `SelectedItem` as the `Type` it is

Example:

```
_fPeriod.FiscalYear = (fiscalYearComboBox.SelectedItem as FiscalPeriod).FiscalYearName;
```

Or if your `ComboBox` `ValueMember` is set to `FiscalYear` you can cast `SelectedValue` as the `Type` `FiscalYear` is

```
_fPeriod.FiscalYear = fiscalYearComboBox.SelectedValue as DateTime;
```

Comment: if fiscalYearComboBox.SelectedItem as FiscalPeriod is not assignable then your code may break

Comment: I'm sure OP can add error handling, I was just showing examples :)